# What is the difference between [::] and * in binding sockets to IPv6 addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, sockets

I'm trying to investigate listening IPv6 sockets on an Ubuntu Server. I don't understand the difference between [::] and *.

Two questions on my mind:

1. Ary there any difference?
2. If not, why they appear in multiple representations?

```
$ ss --listening --tcp --ipv6

State       Recv-Q      Send-Q    Local Addr:Port    Peer Addr:Port                 
LISTEN      0           128            *:http             *:*
LISTEN      0           128            *:8083             *:*
LISTEN      0           128         [::]:ssh           [::]:*
LISTEN      0           128            *:19998            *:*
LISTEN      0           128            *:19999            *:*
```

Comment: Are you sure you executed ss with the --ipv6 parameter? I think * and :: mean the same (bind on all IP addresses) but the first is for ipv4 and the second ipv6

Comment: what about this? https://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket

Comment: it actually truncates all zero'es and shows only `::` instead, so it must be localhost or so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` and `[::]` indicate whether the `IPV6_V6ONLY` flag was set to `false` or `true` during socket creation, respectively.

Example:

```
$ socat UDP6-LISTEN:1234,ipv6only=0 - &
$ socat UDP6-LISTEN:4321,ipv6only=1 - &
$ ss -l -6 -e
Netid             State              Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port                                                                
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                          *:1234                                     *:*                uid:1000 ino:3003972 sk:1 v6only:0 <->             
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                       [::]:4321                                  [::]:*                uid:1000 ino:3004007 sk:2 v6only:1 <->
```

However, this representation is `ss` specific behavior. `netstat` and older versions of `ss` represent both cases as `[::]`. The relevant passage of `ss`'s source can be found [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c#n1599).

The flag's purpose is described within the `ipv6` manpage:

> IPV6_V6ONLY (since Linux 2.4.21 and 2.6)
>
> If  this flag is set to true (nonzero), then the socket is restricted to sending and receiving IPv6 packets only.  In this case, an IPv4 and an IPv6 application can bind to a single port at the same time.
>
> If  this  flag  is  set to false (zero), then the socket can be used to send and receive packets to and from an IPv6 address or an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.
>
> The argument is a pointer to a boolean value in an integer.
>
> The  default  value  for  this  flag  is  defined  by   the   contents   of   the file */proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only*.  The default value for that file is 0 (false).

Comment: I tried your example and both ports are showing as " :::1234 " and "  :::4321 ". Perhaps this is ss version specific? I've got iproute2-ss151103

Comment: @HoD Yes, indeed it seems to be at least `ss` specific. I added your remark to my answer.